# Java: Returning a random value from a given key in a HashMap<String, List<String>>

Tags: java, list, random, hashmap

I am trying to create a method which will return a random value from a list of strings in a hashmap when given a specific key. Here is my code below. (in particular look at the method "getRandomValue" as thats the one im having difficulty on). My question is: How do I look up a key in the map and return a random value from the hashmap?

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Random;

public class Values {
    private Map<String, List<String>> map;
    private static Random rand = new Random();

public void ValueStore() {
    this.map = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();
}

public boolean containsKey(String key) {
    if(map.containsKey(key)) {
        return true;
    } return false;

}

public void put(String key, List<String> value) {
    map = new HashMap<>();
    map.put(key, value);

}

public String getRandomValue(String key) {
    for (String key1 : map.keySet()) {
        if(map.containsKey(key)) {
        //not sure what to do here  
        }
    }
    return key;

}

}
```

Comment: `return list.get(new Random().nextInt(list.size()))` Although I would recommend that you reuse the `Random` instance.

Comment: @BoristheSpider Sorry but I'm confused about how that links to my list of strings in the hashmap i created

Comment: `List<String> list = map.get(key1);`

Comment: I don't understand your loop `containsKey` thing.

Comment: @nissimabehcera why would you try to parse some random `String` as `int`?

Comment: Be aware that by doing `map = new HashMap<>();` in your `put` method, you are *erasing the entire Map* each time `put` is called, so your Map will never have more than one entry.

Comment: @VGR I realised this shortly after, I am struggling  to fix it - what would be the ideal solution?

Comment: `private final Map<String, List<String>> map = new HashMap<>();` would be a good solution.

Comment: @VGR Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all create an instance of `java.util.Random` as a static final field in your class, as your `getRandomValue(String)` method is going to need to use it each time it's called:

```
private static final Random RANDOM = new Random();
```

Now make use of this in your method:

```
public String getRandomValue(String key) {
    List<String> list = map.get(key);
    if (list == null) {
        return null; // or throw an exception
    }
    int randomIndex = RANDOM.nextInt(list.length());
    return list.get(randomIndex);
}
```

The `Random.nextInt(int x)` method will return a value between zero (inclusive) and `x` (exclusive), which makes it perfect for picking a random index (because List and array indices always begin at zero).